# Haskell Runtime Error: error: Prelude.(!!): index too large

Tags: function, haskell, runtime-error, list-comprehension

I have a long and slightly wacky function in Haskell.

```
(#==#) :: String -> String -> Bool
str1 #==# str2 = (sum[ 1 | index <- [0..(max (length str1) (length str2))], (str1!!index == str2!!index || str1!!index == '$')] == (max (length str1) (length str2)))
```

**In short, this function checks if two string are either identical, and considers them identical if they have one or more '$'**
[Long Version: To save you time from deciphering it, it take two strings, an index variable inside the list comprehension goes from 0 until the length of the longest String. Then the element of each String at the current index is compared to eachother or the dollar sign. Both are OK. If they are one of those, a 1 is added to the new list, and if the sum of this new list is equal to the length, then the word is a match.

When I try running this though, I get a peculiar error:

```
*Practice> let totals = (sum[ 1 | index <- [1..(max (length str1) (length str2))], (str1!!index == str2!!index || str1!!index == '$')] == (max (length str1) (length str2)))
*Practice> totals
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

I've been doing research but haven't found any solution to this particular error. If anyone knows anything about it, I would most appreciate it.

(Btw, the "index" in the error is not the same as the index I use in the function)

Comment: `i` goes to the length of the longest string eh?  So what happens when you try to dereference the shorter one at a large index?

Comment: Also, the last valid index is `length list - 1`.

Comment: @Imray, try it with two strings of different lengths...

Comment: `!!` is an effective way to port indexing bugs from other languages to Haskell. (That code looks a lot like a for-loop translated into a list comprehension.)

Answer (score 14):

Falling back on `!!` for this task suggests that you are trying to shoehorn a different language into Haskell. Allow me to point you towards a more Haskelly solution. From what I understand, this function performs a standard string equality test, but the first string is allowed to have the character `$`, which is a "wildcard" that can match any single character.

Recall that `String` in Haskell is nothing more than a list of `Char`. We can therefore pattern match on the two list constructors: empty list, and non-empty list. Matching on both possibilities for both lists gives us four possible combinations:

```
(#==#) :: String -> String -> Bool
[]     #==# []     = ???
(x:xs) #==# []     = ???
[]     #==# (y:ys) = ???
(x:xs) #==# (y:ys) = ???
```

Consider if both lists are empty. Do they match? Let's say that sure, they do. This turns out to be an important base-case choice, but for now I'll simply appeal to the fact that putting empty strings into your original code should produce `True`.

```
[] #==# [] = True
```

Let's look at the middle two cases, where one list is empty, but the other isn't.

```
(x:xs) #==# []     = ???
[]     #==# (y:ys) = ???
```

You never specified what should happen for lists of uneven length. However, to preserve what appears to be your original algorithm, if the first list is filled with `$` then we call it good, otherwise, it's not a match. So we'll inspect the first element of the left-hand list, and if it is `$` then we will keep checking the rest of the list.

```
('$':xs) #==# []    = xs #==# []
(x:xs)   #==# []    = False
[]       #==# (_:_) = False
```

Let's look at the interesting case, the one where both are non-empty.

```
(x:xs) #==# (y:ys) = ???
```

If the left-hand first character is `$`, then we ignore whatever the right character is, and keep checking. If the characters bound to `x` and `y` are equal, then again, we keep checking. If they are unequal, then we stop with a `False`.

```
('$':xs) #==# (_:ys) = xs #==# ys
(x:xs) #==# (y:ys)
  | x == y    = undefined {- exercise to the reader -}
  | otherwise = False
```

This technique uses primitive recursion, rather than list comprehensions. If this seems foreign to you, then I highly recommend that you review [LYAH > Recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) for a good intro to thinking the Haskell way.